# google autocomplete in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, autocomplete

I want to use google autocomplete.
I have already implemented UISearchBar and google map
This is my google map code on viewDidLoad

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
_locationManager.delegate = self;
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.9937266, 72.4987654) zoom:15.0f];
_googleMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapView.bounds camera:camera];
_googleMapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

_googleMapView=_mapView;
_googleMapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = YES;

marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
// marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);

marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.9937266, 72.4987654);
marker.title = @"Ahmedabad";
marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_map_car.png"];
marker.snippet = @"India";
marker.map = self.googleMapView;
```

I want "when I type any location in the search bar it will display on UITableView and when I select that location a pin is set to that location."

I already try https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete but it's not useful.

give me some sample demo.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a really good and easy to use the library for implementing google search with autocomplete text field.

https://github.com/TheMrugraj/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField

**How to USE** : ()

- Bind 'MVPlaceSearchTextField' as Class for 'UITextField' in the
  Storyboard.
- Set its delegate named 'placeSearchDelegate'.
- Set your API Key as value of Property "strApiKey" Create iOS Key to
  use    it here from Google Console, for more info
- Add following in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate.

  ```
  [GMSServicesprovideAPIKey:@"YOUR API KEY"];
  ```

Try following to add a pin for user selected place ,You can add GSMarker with coordinates:

```
-(void)placeSearch:(MVPlaceSearchTextField*)textField ResponseForSelectedPlace:(GMSPlace*)responseDict . {

     CLLocation *userSelectedLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:responseDict.coordinate.latitude longitude:responseDict.coordinate.longitude]; 
     marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userSelectedLocation.coordin‌ate.latitude, userSelectedLocation.coordinate.longitude); 
     marker.map = self.googleMapView; [_googleMapView animateToLocation:userSelectedLocation.coordinate]; 
    [self.googleMapView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:self.googleMapView.camera.target zoom:15.0f]];
}
```

Comment: you just need to load data on a map. It can be apple map or google. It can save all other efforts of getting the text from the field, making a web call, fetching data from response etc..

Comment: this is code

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    //NSLog(@"New Latitude %f  New Longitude %f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    [_googleMapView animateToLocation:currentLocation.coordinate];
    [self.googleMapView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:self.googleMapView.camera.target zoom:15.0f]];
}

but this method is not called...

Comment: [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; call this in view will appear and you need to call this [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; too

Comment: Do you want to enter in region location?

Comment: are you using MVPlaceSearchTextField, or adding a pin from didUpdateLocations: ?

Comment: i'm using MVPlaceSearchTextField.

Comment: you are adding static GMSMarker, add it again from didUpdateLocations:

Comment: `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];   
    marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
    marker.map = self.googleMapView;
    [_googleMapView animateToLocation:currentLocation.coordinate];
    [self.googleMapView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:self.googleMapView.camera.target zoom:15.0f]];
}`

Comment: this delegate -(void)placeSearch:(MVPlaceSearchTextField*)textField ResponseForSelectedPlace:(GMSPlace*)responseDict{ } shows the result user has selected. If you want to update pin on map you need to do in this method.

Comment: okay, can you tell me what code i use in this delegate method so google map show that location?

Comment: did you run the demo? add keys in it and run. Then just replace apple map with google map . You can add GSMarker with coordinates:

Comment: yes brother, i run demo but i'm only using google map, see the question and code of google map..

Comment: yes its working, but when i enter near by city or other city the camera view did not move, otherwise its working perfectly.

Comment: `GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:self.googleMapView.camera.target zoom:8.0f];
    _googleMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapView.bounds camera:camera];`
i just add this code and its working..
thanks man..